# Erreur #1146 Table 'xxxxxxx' dosen't exist'

Tags: mysql, linux, database, phpmyadmin, wampserver

I get  database from server linux debian `/mnt/var/lib/mysql/directorybase` the files `frm` and copy the `directorybase` in   `C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\data`
 my local machine wampserver but I get this error in phpmyadmin when I access my table  in phpmyadmin then error message

> #1146 - Table 'avvvc' doesn't exist.

File log I have this:

> [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table avis_prod/sib_model_forms from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the `.frm` file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.

Comment: Are you able to see `'avvvc'` table in phpmyadmin ?

Comment: yes i see when i click  i get #1146 Table 'xxxxxxx' dosen't exist'

Comment: Copying database files from one OS to another, especially if you copy InnoDB tables to a different filesystem or OS with different settings for case sensitivity will most likely fail. The main problem are the settings of  the case sensitivity in the filesystem, which will result in files that are not found. The only save way to copy the data form one OS to another is to do a mysqldump and import.

Comment: Do an EXPORT on the unix box and then IMPORT the backup file on WAMPServer. Thats the only really safe way to move databases from one machine to another

Comment: Also INNODB databases have at least part of the data in the file called `ibdata1` so just copying the `databasename\folder structure` as you might with a MYISAM database will never work. As likely as not the data is actually in `ibdata1` so `Export/Import`